# New-TransportRule for appending disclaimers

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

This is pretty straightforward. I tried creating a rule in the EAC for sent messages, but it's not working as intended. Basically I need to create a rule that checks if any recipients (To, CC or BCC) are from outside my org. If there are any, append a disclaimer to EVERYONE in the recipients (including inside the org).

Doing this via the EAC doesn't work in the sense that when I specify the rule "If the message... is sent to 'Outside the organization' " it finds ONLY recipients outside the org and appends the disclaimer to them. However, I also need to append it for users inside the org if this condition verifies. Unfortunately doing it like this only recipients from outside the org are receiving the appended disclaimer, but not company workers.

I've been working with PS quite a lot lately and New-TransportRule seems to be the way to go to do this, but reading through the documentation hasn't helped me a lot on how to structure said query to do exactly what I want or even how to only apply it to one person for testing purposes.

Any of you guys worked with this cmdlet before and could give me a quick hand?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's been some time since I've managed Exchange, but judging from [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/new-transportrule?view=exchange-ps#parameters), I'd say you could probably take advantage of the `AnyOfRecipientAddressMatchesPatterns` predicate (emphasis added):

> `-AnyOfRecipientAddressMatchesPatterns`
>
> [...]
>
> The `AnyOfRecipientAddressMatchesPatterns` parameter **specifies a
> condition that looks for text patterns in recipient email addresses by
> using regular expressions**. You can specify multiple text patterns by
> using the following syntax: "Regular expression1","Regular
> expression2",..."Regular expressionN".
>
> **A match for this condition applies the rule action to all recipients
> of the message**. For example, if the action is to reject the message,
> the message is rejected for all recipients of the message, not just
> for the specified recipients.

So let's start by constructing an appropriate pattern:

```
# Define internal recipient domains
$internalDomains = 'ress.tld','internal.ress.tld','ress-alias.tld'

# Escape as literal regex pattern
$internalDomains = $internalDomains |ForEach-Object { [regex]::Escape($_) }

# Embed in negative look-behind pattern
$nonInternalDomainPattern = "(?<!@(?:$($internalDomains -join '|')))"
```

The resulting regex pattern will match any email *not* having any of the three domains listed:

```
PS ~> $nonInternalDomainPattern
(?<!@(?:ress\.tld|internal\.ress\.tld|ress-alias\.tld))$
PS ~> 'ress@ress.tld' -match $nonInternalDomainPattern           # doesn't match on internal recipients
False
PS ~> 'iisresetme@example.org' -match $nonInternalDomainPattern  # but it matches any other address
True
```

Now you just need to include it in a transport rule:

```
New-TransportRule "Disclaimer on all external communications" -AnyOfRecipientAddressMatchesPatterns $nonInternalDomainPattern -ApplyHtmlDisclaimerText '<your>html goes here</your>'
```

Comment: Hey Mathias. Thanks for the reply, but I don't think this would be the solution for this specific case. Applying disclaimers to ONLY people outside my org I am able to do already. What I am not able to do, however, is apply disclaimers to people INSIDE my org when an e-mail recipient contains someone from outside my org, but only then.  
The expected behavior would be: internal e-mails have no disclaimer text appended. When someone from outside the org is found in the recipients, everyone included in the recipients (inside or outside) receives the append. Hope that made sense!

Comment: @Ress you didn't really read the answer, did you? :-)

Comment: Sorry maybe I'm doing something wrong. I tested the solution, but the html-to-append is still appending for messages being sent between members inside the org. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Ress Did you include all your primary email domains in the `$internalDomains` list before generating the regex pattern? If so, I have no idea :-)

Comment: I believe so. We only have one so currently all I have is: `$internalDomains = 'company.com'`

Comment: I understand the wanted behavior is quite odd to begin with. Just wanted to check if something like that would even be possible

Comment: @Ress The only other thing that comes to mind: try deleting the rule again and then add it with the `-UseLegacyRegex` switch to see if it makes a difference

Comment: Unfortunately still nothing. My external e-mail is receiving the appended html, but the internal one is not

Comment: While @MathiasR.Jessen  has (as always) given terific information, In my Exchange experience, RegEx Transport Rule predicates are very unreliable.  It doesn't matter how perfectly you write the expression.  In a rule, I've never even tried something as complex as a look behind, but generally anything more complicated that a "^" & "$" anchors has been iffy.  It's always surprised me, given the assumption of .Net under the hood.  Occasionally I've tried to research the particulars but have come up empty every time. I hope I'm wrong, but otherwise, I'm sorry for the bad news.